# How does paypal rest sdk identify which card number belong to which card type?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Im trying to integrate paypal payment system via paypal-rest-node sdk, and I'm a little bit confused on how to tell which card numbers belong to which card types

For example

These are the codes, that i straight copy from their github page, but in one of their information, it says `"type:" "visa"`. So technically on the clientside a user would type in something and then they would click form submit to send the data to the server. but Im kinda confused on the type.

```
var card_data = {
  "type": "visa",
  "number": "4417119669820331",
  "expire_month": "11",
  "expire_year": "2018",
  "cvv2": "123",
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shopper"
};

paypal.creditCard.create(card_data, function(error, credit_card){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  } else {
    console.log("Create Credit-Card Response");
    console.log(credit_card);
  }
})
```

couldn't the API tells which card numbers belong to which card type?

Comment: I reckon you can mask some digits in the card number and it will give the card type

Comment: mask some digits, where do i refer to? any api?

Comment: You can check this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/credit-card-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a module like [credit-card-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/credit-card-type)

```
let creditCardType = require('credit-card-type');

let visaCards = creditCardType(yourCCNumber);
console.log(visaCards[0].type);  // Type
```

Comment: I have another question, if you know how to solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921540/how-do-i-make-a-direct-payment-using-paypal-rest-in-node