# How do i make a direct payment using paypal-rest in node?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I found a library that paypal themselves have written for [node](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK), they wrote a great library on how to pay. Im still in the confused state on how to receive payment and Im running out of time right now.

The use case is very simple, User A click add an item to his cart , then he has a choice, its either to pay using Credit/debit card or paypal(express checkout)

My goal still at the credit/debit card, where user decided to use credit/debit card to receive payments, and im using paypal-rest-api sdk to do this. But looking at the code samples Im super confused on which sample to choose, from

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/tree/master/samples

```
var card_data = {
  "type": "visa",
  "number": "4417119669820331",
  "expire_month": "11",
  "expire_year": "2018",
  "cvv2": "123",
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shopper"
};

paypal.creditCard.create(card_data, function(error, credit_card){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  } else {
    console.log("Create Credit-Card Response");
    console.log(credit_card);
  }
})
```

In the `card_data`, there is no amount, and im really confused.

Again the use case

User could buy the item on website, and he pays using credit/debit card and it will automatically send the money from his bank account to my paypal business account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at not the right method. You need `payment.create`

Here's the code snippet from [payment documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_credit_card.js)

```
var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "credit_card",
        "funding_instruments": [{
            "credit_card": {
                "type": "visa",
                "number": "4417119669820331",
                "expire_month": "11",
                "expire_year": "2018",
                "cvv2": "874",
                "first_name": "Joe",
                "last_name": "Shopper",
                "billing_address": {
                    "line1": "52 N Main ST",
                    "city": "Johnstown",
                    "state": "OH",
                    "postal_code": "43210",
                    "country_code": "US"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": "7",
            "currency": "USD",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": "5",
                "tax": "1",
                "shipping": "1"
            }
        },
        "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }]
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("Create Payment Response");
        console.log(payment);
    }
});
```

Comment: so i just need to replace the data with `req.body.data`?

Comment: For example `"amount": { "total": req.body.price }`?

Comment: Yes looks like that

Comment: I want to ask you one more question, if you don't mind, For express checkout which payment method should i use?

Comment: I think you should use the frontend library for that, but I'm not raally proficient with PayPal SDK